# Django-- Deactivate User account instead of deleting it

Tags: django, authentication, django-models

I want to deactivate the User account instead of deleting it. I want to do something like user.is_active = False. I have a view to delete User profile and it works but now I need to change it to only deactivate. 
Here is my view:

```
def delete_profile(request):
    user = User.objects.filter(id = request.user.profile.user_id)
    try:
        user.delete()
    except:
        messages.error(request,'Please try again.')
        return redirect('profile')

    messages.success(request, 'Profile successfully deleted.')
    return redirect('index')
```

I tried User.is_active = False , it displays the success message but doesn't do anything. When I check the User in admin panel it will still have User marked as active.

Any Idea how I can achieve this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should show the code that didn't work. From your description though, you're doing a few things wrong.

First, `.filter()` always returns a queryset, not an instance. To get an instance, you should use `.get()`.

Secondly, `User` is the class; the instance is `user`.

Thirdly, you have **no reason** to do a query here at all. `request.user` is *already* the User instance. There is no need to take that user, get its profile, ask the profile for the user ID, then do another query to get back the user you started with. Just use the user you already have.

Finally, **never, ever** do a blank `except`, as that will catch all sorts of unexpected errors and hide anything that could be going wrong. Only catch exceptions you actually know how to deal with. In this case, there is nothing specific you need to handle; if anything unexpected goes wrong, let Django report that error normally.

```
def delete_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    user.is_active = False
    user.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Profile successfully disabled.')
    return redirect('index')
```

Answer (score 3):

You may need to set `user.is_active = False` and then save the `user` object.

```
def delete_profile(request):        
    user = request.user
    user.is_active = False
    user.save()
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, 'Profile successfully disabled.')
    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: @Daniel Roseman, Actually, there are much more logical errors in this view. Sorry, for being so ignorant. If I may ask, seeing that you have much more experience and knowledge regarding this context, should user need to be logged out after this so-called deletion??

Comment: and if I use the query, the code doesn't work. I simply did user = request.user and it worked

Comment: Yes, that's much better code than mine. Learned something new. Thanks man.

Comment: @FazilZaid good point about logout. I'm pretty sure that the middleware will mark the user as anonymous on the next page load, but it'd be worth making that explicit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save it too:

```
user.is_active = False
user.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

After calling `user.is_active = False` you need to write the changes to the database by calling `user.save()`