# Django: Delete ForeignKey instance but keep some of its data on record (for Ecom)

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say you have 2 ecom related models: `User` and `Order`.

On the `Order`, you want to keep the `User`'s data because there's a transaction that occurred, and you'd most likely like to keep the customers info, however, you'd also like to allow the customer to delete their account should they choose.

For example, the way I see it is something like:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models


class Order(models.Model):
    customer_email = models.EmailField()
    customer_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    customer_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    customer = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=SET_NULL)

    def clean(self):
        if not self.customer_first_name:
            self.customer_first_name = self.customer.first_name
        if not self.customer_last_name:
            self.customer_last_name = self.customer.last_name
        if not self.customer_email:
            self.customer_email = self.customer.email

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But that seems like a bunch of duplication.

Is there a way to go about building that without duplication, or do you just have to live with writing the same fields from the `User` model but with different names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your customer wants to delete his account, you just set `is_active=False` and an inactive user cant log in to your system any more. that's a best practice.

*Delete a user record from your database is not a good decision.*

This way you don't need to store the reference of a customer to another table when the user deletes their account. is_active=False we mean it we deleted the custom.

Here you go for such example in another post:

[Django-- Deactivate User account instead of deleting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903773/django-deactivate-user-account-instead-of-deleting-it/44923980)